# Make running tests mandatory before runserver in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, django-rest-framework

Is there any way to make running tests compulsory before running the server in django? I have a project on which many people will be working on so i want to make the testing compulsory before running it and all tests must pass before it runs. So basically lock the runserver command until all the tests pass successfully. **This implementation will be just for some time and not for long.**

Comment: They're developers. The first time this stops them doing what they wanted to do they'll comment out a single line to bypass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @LFDMR that this is probably a bad idea and will make your development process really inefficient. Even when with test-driven development, it is perfectly sensible to use the development server, for example, to figure out why your tests don't pass. I think you would be better served with a Git pre-commit or pre-push hook or the equivalent in your version control system.

That being said, here is how you can achieve what you are after:

You can overwrite an existing management command by adding a management command of the same name to one of your apps.

So you have to create file `management/commands/runserver.py` in one of your apps which looks like this:

```
from django.core import management
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import BaseRunserverCommand


class Command(BaseRunserverCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
         call_command('test')  # calls `sys.exit(1)` on test failure
         super().handle(*args, **kwargs)
```

If I were a developer in your team, the first thing I would do is deleting this file ;)

Comment: call test right after runserver how would we do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this line `execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0], 'test'])` before `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)` in function `main()` in module `manage.py`. It can solve your problem. The `main()` will look like this:

```
def main():
    # settings, import execute_from_command_line in 'try except' block
    if (os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') != 'true') & (sys.argv[1] == 'runserver'): # just run once when execute command 'manage.py runserver' but not other commands
        execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0], 'test']) # run ALL the test first
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

or you can specify the module for testing: `execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0], 'test', 'specific_module'])`
or with file pattern:
`execute_from_command_line([sys.argv[0], 'test', '--pattern=tests*.py'])`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it will be a terrible idea.

What you should really look into is [Continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)

It is whenever someone push something all tests should run and a email will be send to the user who have pushed is something fail.

Comment: Yeah i understand that but it will there for short time and not a long term implementation.

Comment: In that case you could made a quick bash script like `./manage.py test && ./manage.py runserver`